# How to inject bower dependencies in karma.conf.js file with gulp?

Tags: gulp, karma-runner, bower, wiredep

How to inject bower dependencies in karma.conf.js file with gulp?
I tried wiredep task - but it doesn't work with .js files and it inserts  tag with path to dependency, but I need just path in quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case the version of wiredep you're making use of doesn't support .js files, you can include the **fileTypes** node in your wiredep configuration file. This is what I have in my project:

**wiredep Configuration:**

```
...,
src:
[
  '<%= myApp.webRoot %>/index.html',
  './karma.conf.js'
],
...,
fileTypes: {
  js: {
    block: /(([ \t]*)\/\/\s*bower:*(\S*))(\n|\r|.)*?(\/\/\s*endbower)/gi,
    detect: {
      js: /['\']([^'\']+\.js)['\'],?/gi,
      css: /['\']([^'\']+\.js)['\'],?/gi
    },
    replace: {
      js: '"{{filePath}}",',
      css: '"{{filePath}}",'
    }
  }
},
...
```

**kamra.conf.js**

```
...,
files:
[
  // bower:js

  // endbower
  'your/other/**/dependencies/*.here.js'
],
...
```

Also, make sure that the path to your **karma.conf.js** is correct as even if the file is not found you won't get any warnings or errors.